# Emma: "nothing to do: no metadata found in any of the data files"

Tags: android, ant, emma, test-coverage

I'm trying to use emma code coverage with Android. Everything works well except the creation of coverage.em - it is not created. I've tried to look for it (in the virtual device and also in the test and app folder), but I can't find it.

I have looked for any other solution but I've found nothing that works for me.

Thanks all...

EDIT: now it generates the coverage.em but it say (using verbose mode): "merged coverage data contains 0 entries" and the reports are 0%. 
What's wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you manage to generate the coverage.em file?

Answer (score 0):

I get the coverage report successfully by following steps:

0.install ant on my system

1.(in the sdk/tools dir)

```
android update project -p <path to app project>
```

2.(in the sdk/tools dir)

```
android update test-project -m <path to app project> -p <path to test project>
```

3.(in the test project root dir)

```
ant clean emma debug install test
```

4.the report is /bin/coverage.html